# Мгновенная запись DataInputStream в socket

Tags: java, сокет, tcp

Всех приветствую. Я пытаюсь сделать что-то вроде real-time video streaming'a.

Появилась такая проблема:

Очень низкая скорость передачи данных client-server-client.

Если убрать из этой цепочки server (client-client via wifi) - то изображения передаются мгновенно, при этом в 15 fps.

Я подозреваю, что это из-за того, что я сначала ЧИТАЮ данные от одного клиента, а потом уже записываю их в сокет другого.

Можно ли как-то сразу записывать входящие данные?

Код:

```
public class ServerCom {

    void MainMethod() throws IOException {

        ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(9191);

        System.out.println("Server started");

        Socket mSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();

        System.out.println("First socket was connected");

        mSocket.setKeepAlive(true);

        Socket SECOND_SOCKET = welcomeSocket.accept();

        System.out.println("Second socket was connected");

        SECOND_SOCKET.setKeepAlive(true);

        OutputStream os = SECOND_SOCKET.getOutputStream();

        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);

        InputStream inStream = null;

        inStream = mSocket.getInputStream();

        DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(inStream);

        while (true) {
            try {

                // Смотрим, новое ли изображение

                int token = is.readInt();

                if (token == 4) {
                    dos.writeInt(4);
                    if (is.readUTF().equals("#@@#")) {
                        // если оно новое - отсылаем клиенту уведомление о том, что оно новое
                        dos.writeUTF("#@@#");
                        int imgLength = is.readInt();
                        // берем размер входящего изображения и отсылаем его на сокет 2-го клиента
                        dos.writeInt(imgLength);
                        // заканчиаем отсылвать размер, начинаем слать само изображение 
                        dos.writeUTF("-@@-");
                        dos.flush();

                        byte[] buffer = new byte[imgLength];
                        int len = 0;

                        // записываем в буффер изображение

                        while (len < imgLength) {
                            len += is.read(buffer, len, imgLength - len);
                        }

                        // отправляем его

                        dos.write(buffer);
                        dos.flush();

                        System.out.println("Send to second socket");

                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Возможно, на сервере используется [алгоритм Нейгла](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0), задерживающий отправку данных. Попробуйте добавить строку `SECOND_SOCKET.setTcpNoDelay(true);` рядом с `mSocket.setKeepAlive(true);`.

Comment: Я бы попробовал добавить buffered стримы. Вы пишите данные мелкими кусками напрямую в сокет.

Comment: @Zergatul, хм, хорошая идея. А не могли бы вы набросать пример для моего когда? Никак не могу внедрить его к себе :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как вы пишите данные мелкие кусками, стоит попробовать буферизированные потоки:

```
OutputStream os = SECOND_SOCKET.getOutputStream();
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
// теперь DataOutputStream будет писать в буферизированный стрим
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);
```

Как заметил @zRrr в комментах, вы читаете весь массив байт, а только потом пишете его в другой стрим. Можно сделать лучше. Вместо:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[imgLength];
int len = 0;

// записываем в буффер изображение

while (len < imgLength) {
    len += is.read(buffer, len, imgLength - len);
}

// отправляем его

dos.write(buffer);
dos.flush();
```

Вот так:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int len = 0;

while (len < imgLength) {
    // прочитали кусок
    int read = is.read(buffer, len, Math.min(imgLength - len, buffer.length));
    // и сразу записываем его
    dos.write(buffer, 0, read);
    // не нужно здесь вызывать flush, вызовем его 1 раз в конце
    len += read;
}

dos.flush();
```